# Selecting options from radio button and display date picker by PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, datepicker, radio-button

I am implementing a data recordset table.

I would like to create 2 radio buttons for user selects the option to control my data table.

For example, the radio buttons are: (imagine the interface as describe below)
- View by Month: ['month' drop-down list] - ['year' drop-down list]
- View by Date: Start Date: [date picker] to End Date: [date picker]

If my customer want to view the table with March only. He needs to select [View by Month] radio button, and then select month and year drop-down list.

If my customer want to view certain date of periods, she needs to select [View by Date] radio button, and then pick the date on the box (I assume Javascript

I have search round the Q&A in stackoverflow, but have no idea which one suitable to implement into my codes that written in PHP, I have no Javascript nor jQuery knowledge, **I hope can get a simplest solution.**

I want to pass this parameter to a URL and retrieve the data recordset onto my page.

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to use Javascript to take the values of the select inputs and generate an Ajax request to build the correct results

or

Turn the options into a proper form and provide a submit button which will post the values to a particular script which will build the results and then render the same page containing the amended results.

Check out jQuery. The docs are fairly straight forward and will give you a good opportunity to see how to achieve even more awesome stuff using javascript.